# Get how much of a view is visible in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview, opacity

I have a React Native ScrollView filled with images - one image at a time, scrolling vertically. Now, when an Image is coming into view or going out of view, I want its transparency to be a function of how much of the is visible. I.e. if I have scrolled a view half in or half out of the viewport, I want its transparency to be 0.5, if it is fully in I want it to be 1.0, and when it's fully out of sight I want it to be 0.0. In iOS I would use the UIScrollView delegate function scrollViewDidScroll to achieve this. How do I do this in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing was actually not that different from what I could on iOS. On ScrollView I added a ref stored in this._scrollView and an onScroll function where I would use findNodeHandle to get the scrollHeight:

```
var scrollHandle = findNodeHandle(this._scrollView)
RCTUIManager.measure(findNodeHandle(scrollHandle), (x, y, width, height, px, py) => {
  this._scrollHeight = height
})
```

Then for each image I could similarly use the `py` variable and height to see if py was less than 0 or if py + height was greater than the window. If so, calculate transparency based on those values.